# Make a child div inside a parent div y-scrollable if child gets too big

Tags: html, css

Here's my problem, it's quite uncommon so this is why I ask the question here:

I have a parent div, called `middle` (which is itself inside a parent div called `row`, its height is set to 315px). This `middle` contains two divs, `div1` and `scrollable_div`.

`div1` has a determined height that is not meant to change. On the other hand, the `scrollable_div` contains a list that is meant to evolve (through javascript method), which means if the list contains too many elements, it will end up overlapping and do some crazy stuff as soon as the list reaches the row's height. I would like a scroll to appear in order not to totally wreck this good-looking page when the list gets too big.

Here a codepen : http://codepen.io/Yocto/pen/qZXQjm where `elname`stands for *element name*. (row1 has a purple background and the not-so-scrollable list has an orange one).

Don't hesitate to tell me if what I want isn't quite understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set a height for the scrollable div and then set the y overflow property....

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/Unused/pen/QNMJre)

```
.scrollable_div { height:130px; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

Comment: This is actually something I got earlier on before asking this question. The problem though is, that if I zoom in on the page, it'll the list will still end up going further than the video's height...